# eventos onclik na table não funcionam

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho uma tabela em um arquivo php com alguns eventos `onclick` que preciso chamar depois que a pagina é carregada. 
Mas quando tento clicar em um dos valores ou botão `input submit` não há reação. segue o código. Desde já agradeço se alguém poder ajudar.

```
<div style='overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: scroll; width: 1200px; height: 400px;'> 

    <form method="POST" id="formIdJog">

    <input type="hidden" id="id_jogo" name="quejogo">

    <table id="tabela_escolha_jogos" class="lista-jogos">
    <tr>
    <th>Time A</th>
    <th>Time B</th>
    <th>Data-Hora</th>
    <th>Campeonatos</th>
    <th>Casa</th>
    <th>Empate</th>
    <th>Fora</th>
    <th>Mais</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    function formDt($dt){
        //21/12/2016 17:30
        $ano = substr($dt, 0, 4);
        $mes = substr($dt,5, 2);
        $dia = substr($dt,8, 2);
        $hora = substr($dt,11, 2);
        $min = substr($dt,14, 2);
        return $dia . '/' . $mes . '/' . $ano . ' - ' . $hora . ':' . $min;
        //return new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia, hora, min, 0);
    }

    $decodifi = file_get_contents("http://pansudopoker.com/futebolapi/api/CampJogos");
     $dados = json_decode($decodifi, true);

        foreach($campeonatos as $campeonato){ //ta no select

            echo "<tr style='background-color: #008000;'> 
            <td>
            <span name='camp'>".$campeonato['CAMP_NOME']."</span>
            </td>
            </tr>";

            foreach($dados as $dado){
                $dia = substr($dado['dt_hr_ini'], 8, 2); 
                $data = formDt($dado['dt_hr_ini']);
                if($dado["esporte"] == "Futebol" && $dado['Odds'] != null && $dia >= date('d') && 
                $campeonato['CAMP_NOME'] == $dado['camp_nome']):
                $cod = $dado['camp_jog_id'];?>

                <tr id='id_linha' onclick='escolheJogos(this), calcPremio()' >
                <td>
                <span name='id_timea'><?php echo $dado['casa_time']?></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                <span name='id_timeb'><?php echo $dado['visit_time'] ?></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                <span name='id_data'><?php echo $data ?></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                <span><?php echo $dado['camp_nome'] ?></span> 
                </td>
                <td>
                <span name='id_casa' onclick=escolhaCotacao(0)><?php echo $dado['Odds'][0]['taxa'] ?> </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                <span name='id_empate' onclick=escolhaCotacao(1)><?php echo $dado['Odds'][1]['taxa'] ?></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                <a href="javascript:escolhaCotacao(2)"><?php echo $dado['Odds'][2]['taxa'] ?> </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                <button id='id_sub' type='submit' onclick=insere(this)> <?php echo $cod ?> </button>  
                </td>
                </tr>

                <?php endif;
           }
          // return;
        }
    ?> 
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: aonde está sua função insere() ? Poste-a tbm.

Comment: function insere(ref) {
        var codigo = $(ref).val();

Comment: desculpa e function insere(ref) {
        var codigo = $(ref).text();}

Answer (score 0):

O onclick do seu button submit está sem aspas.

```html
<td>
  <button id='id_sub' type='submit' onclick=insere(this)> <?php echo $cod ?> </button>  
</td>
```

Deverá ficar assim

```html
<td>
  <button id='id_sub' type='submit' onclick='insere(this)'> <?php echo $cod ?> </button>  
</td>
```

Comment: amigo ainda não funciona. notei que a ultima linha da tabela visivel no monitor funciona, as demais superiores não.